# How to run these Unix type commands on Windows with PHP

Tags: windows, command-line

I have found a PHP project that wraps all the main command line image optimizer's, this is something I have been looking for, for a while now.

The problem I am having so far is I am wanting to run this on a Windows system.  Below are some of the commands that are run from the scripts.

So my question would be, how would I go about running these external programs on my windows system, they do have windows versions, it's just a matter of getting this PHP to call the correct commands.

So things like `/usr/bin/identify` how would this translate to being ran on a Windows system?

```
exec("/usr/bin/identify -quiet -format \"%m\" $file_path", $return, $error);

$cmd = "/usr/bin/jpegtran -copy none -progressive -optimize $src_file > $dest_file";

$cmd = "/usr/bin/convert $src_file $raw_file";

exec("/usr/bin/pngcrush -rem alla -brute -reduce $raw_file $dest_file");

$cmd = "/usr/bin/gifsicle -O2 $src_file > $dest_file";

$cmd = "/usr/bin/pngquant -ordered 256 $src_file";

 $cmd = "/usr/bin/pngout -c3 -d8 -y -force $quant_file $out_file";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These aren't really Unix-specific apps. They're a variety of graphics-editing programs. Most or all of them are probably available on Windows; you just need to install them (the way somebody else already installed them on the Unix box that your script was originally written for).

The only Unix-specific thing here is the path where it looks for the programs (`/usr/bin` for everything in your example). On Windows, apps typically install to a subdirectory under either `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

`identify` and `convert` are part of [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). You would need to download and install it, and then change the `exec` call to point to the path where the EXEs were installed (e.g. under `C:\Program Files`). Since the install path will probably contain spaces, you'll need to quote it, e.g.:

```
exec("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ImageMagick-6.6.1-Q16\\identify\" -quiet -format \"%m\" $file_path", $return, $error);
```

The other apps you're running -- `jpegtran`, `pngcrush`, `gifsicle`, `pngquant`, and `pngout` -- are separate apps. You can Google them to find their individual download pages.

Comment: Great, I just didn't know how to call them from Windows, so I just have to call there location, thanks, I'll probably install them all into a the directory of this app

Comment: 1 more question about the path, I have optipng installed at `E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\OptiPNG\optipng.exe` would I need to use `E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\OptiPNG\` or `E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\OptiPNG\optipng.exe` when I run the command on it?  Same with ImageMagick `E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\ImageMagick\identify` should it have the .exe extension in this path or just to the folder?

Comment: You need to give the filename, so if it's e.g. `X:\Foo\Foo.exe` you need to say either `X:\Foo\Foo.exe` or just `X:\Foo\Foo` -- that is, you can leave off the trailing `.exe` but you need everything else.